# AHK: Remove Duplicates While Parsing Text Into Array

Tags: arrays, loops, sorting, parsing, autohotkey

I work at a doctors office doing the billing, and I've been writing code to streamline the billing process. I must include all diagnoses in the billing software, so I copy the whole chart, and parse it into an array by newlines looking for the prefix ICD-10, and if two codes are on the same line, it separates those too (via a comma). Before that, it removes a part (if it exists) of the chart that includes canceled procedures so the canceled procedures aren't charged. Sometimes, multiple of the same diagnosis is included in the chart for the purpose of ordering a procedure (it's automatic), and I need to only add each diagnosis to the array once.

```
        [...]
        SendInput, ^a
        ClipBoard :=
        SendInput, ^c
        ClipWait
        BlockInput, MouseMoveOff
        lString := ClipBoard
        Sleep, 200
        IfInString, lString, Canceled Orders
            {
            lStringLeft := SubStr(lString, 1, InStr(lString, "Canceled Orders")-1)
            Sleep, 20
            lStringRight := SubStr(lString, InStr(lString, "Allergies as of"))
            Sleep, 20
            lString :=
            Sleep, 20
            lString := lStringLeft
            Sleep, 20
            lString .= lStringRight
            Sleep, 20
            }
        DxArr := []
        numDx := 0
        Loop, Parse, lString, `n
            If InStr(A_LoopField, "ICD-10")
                Loop, Parse, A_LoopField, `,
                    DxArr[++numDx] := Trim(SubStr(A_LoopField, InStr(A_LoopField, ":") + 1), " `t`n`r")
        [...]
```

The ideal output for

> Essential Hypertension
>
> ICD-9-CM: 401.0
>
> ICD-10-CM: I10
>
> Essential Hypertension with Chronic Kidney Disease, Stage 3
>
> ICD-9-CM: 585.3, 401.0
>
> ICD-10-CM: N18.3, I10

is

> I10 N18.3

I've been at this with several different solutions I found on the internet, but so far, they've just made a mess rather than actually fixing any problem. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash to remove duplicates.  Use your code as the key and a dummy for the value. I use "true" below as the dummy value.  Duplicate records have the same key so they replace the previous key-value pair.

Output the hash's keys after you are done parsing the input.

```
DxHash := {}
Loop, Parse, lString, `n
  If InStr(A_LoopField, "ICD-10")
    Loop, Parse, A_LoopField, `,
      DxHash[Trim(SubStr(A_LoopField, InStr(A_LoopField, ":") + 1), " `t`n`r")] := true

for diagnosis,dummy in DxHash
  send %diagnosis%{SPACE}
```

Comment: I tried doing this with the other code you posted. Copying the method to remove duplicates from the flu shot txt comparer, it looks roughly the same, but I couldn't get it to work. Thanks! This turns the DxArr (now DxHash) into an associative array, right? Is there a way to find the size of an associative array? Because I use numDx as part of a check down below, just after all the codes are finished being entered. it looks like
    If (Index == numDx) and Mod(Index, 4) != 0
         SendInput{Enter}
 Though I'm thinking this might be excessive checking, it may work without the index check.

Comment: Got it. It's low level, but I just do the exact same for loop right before printing, but to count the elements. So it's like For Dx, Element in DxHash numDx++ then after that, the print for loop. Again, it's low level, but it is working.